# Best way to learn econometrics for application?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

I am very interested in the subject, but want to gain understanding on application that can be useful on the job.

Comment: It rather depends on your job

Comment: To broad to answer. Specify, you are interested in general? financial? micro? macro?

Comment: Start playing around with your data in the software of choice. Try to replicate studies and take parts in competition on Kaggle.com that you think are relevant.